# Docker Redis Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Tags: node.js, docker, express, redis, econnrefused

I'm following a tutorial from youtube creating a simple dockerized CRUD application in Express, Node.js, Mongo & Redis. I stucked at video 3:06:57 on Authentication with sessions & Redis.

The initial issue I faced below when I send a POST

```
ClientClosedError: The client is closed
    at Commander._RedisClient_sendCommand (/app/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:408:31)
    at Commander.commandsExecutor (/app/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:166:154)
    at Commander.BaseClass.<computed> [as set] (/app/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/commander.js:8:29)
    at RedisStore.set (/app/node_modules/connect-redis/lib/connect-redis.js:65:21)
    at Session.save (/app/node_modules/express-session/session/session.js:72:25)
    at Session.save (/app/node_modules/express-session/index.js:406:15)
    at ServerResponse.end (/app/node_modules/express-session/index.js:335:21)
    at ServerResponse.send (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:221:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at exports.login (/app/controllers/authController.js:45:28)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I found out that the issue above was due to Redis version, the tutorial video was using Redis 3.0+ if not mistaken , but I'm having Redis 6.0+ .So I added the line `redisClient.connect().catch(console.error);` but second issue happen.

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1138:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 6379
}
```

the source files as below:

`index.js`:

```js
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const redis = require("redis");
let RedisStore = require("connect-redis")(session);

const { MONGO_PASSWORD, MONGO_IP, MONGO_PORT, MONGO_USER, REDIS_URL, REDIS_PORT, SESSION_SECRET } = require("./config/config");


let redisClient = redis.createClient({
    host: REDIS_URL,
    port: REDIS_PORT,
})

// let redisClient = createClient({ 
//     host: REDIS_URL,
//     port: REDIS_PORT 
// });
 
//redisClient.connect().catch(console.error);

redisClient.on('error', err => {console.log('Error ' + err);});
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version : "3"
services :
  node-app:
    build : .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - PORT=3000
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - mongo-db:/data/db

  redis:
    image: redis
    
volumes:
  mongo-db:
```

`docker-compose.dev.yml`:

```yaml
version : "3"
services :
  node-app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        NODE_ENV: development
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - MONGO_USER=admin
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=password
      - SESSION_SECRET=secret
      
    command: npm run dev
  mongo:
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```

`config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    MONGO_IP: process.env.MONGO_IP || "mongo",
    MONGO_PORT: process.env.MONGO_PORT || 27017,
    MONGO_USER: process.env.MONGO_USER,
    MONGO_PASSWORD: process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD,
    REDIS_URL: process.env.REDIS_URL || "redis",
    REDIS_PORT: process.env.REDIS_PORT || 6379,
    SESSION_SECRET: process.env.SESSION_SECRET 
}
```

I did a check to the redis container logs and it's up and running. Also it should be in the same network with the node-app.

docker command : `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up -d`

Full source code from tutor https://github.com/Sanjeev-Thiyagarajan/node-docker

Comment: please use `redisClient.on('error', err => {console.log('Error ' + err);});` for connecting to redis and let me know about result.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 indicates that your app thinks the URL for Redis is `localhost`. It needs to be `redis`.

Comment: Your question seems to contain links six image files, but no actual source code.  Can you [edit] the question to include the relevant source code and error messages in the question itself (not behind links) as plain text (not images)?

Comment: Hi @xirehat , i replaced the line as mentioned , the result go back to my initial error : /app/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:408
        return Promise.reject(new errors_1.ClientClosedError());
                              ^
ClientClosedError: The client is closed
    ..

Comment: Hi @HansKilian , I do run the app in a localhost environment. They are dockerized and should be within the same network.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze , thanks for the feedback, forgive me as this is my first post here, I don't know the features well. I've insert the code to my question.

Answer (score 13):

Redis client doesn't work in v4 of Redis. Replace the redisClient code with this:

```
let redisClient = redis.createClient({
    legacyMode: true,
    socket: {
        port: REDIS_PORT,
        host: REDIS_URL
    }
})

redisClient.connect().catch(console.error)
```

Comment: In my case, I wasn't adding port & host to inside the 'socket' key

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this code and it solves the problem at 100%.

```js
let redisClient = redis.createClient({
  legacyMode: true,
  socket: {
    port: REDIS_PORT,
    host: REDIS_URL
  }
});
    
redisClient.connect().catch(console.error)
```

Comment: This is the exact same code that the other answer posted.

Comment: Yeah this the exact same code that other posted. And it works perfectly i just wanted to let people know that.